# How to represent a binomial tree in memory

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures

I've got such a structure, is described as a "binomial tree". Let'see a drawing:
[image]

Which is the best way to represent this in memory? Just to clarify, is not a simple binary tree since the node N4 is both the left child of N1 and the right child of N2, the same sharing happens for N7 and N8 and so on... I need a construction algorithm tha easily avoid to duplicates such nodes, but just referencing them.

**UPDATE** 
Many of us does not agree with the "binomial tree deefinition" but this cames from finance ( expecially derivative pricing ) have a look here: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter45.html for example. So I used the "Domain acceted definition".

Comment: That's not even a tree. And the actual [binomial tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_tree#Binomial_tree) looks different.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by “best”? What are you looking for? Code readability? Memory footprint? Performance? Isn't a simple type with `left` and `right` references enough?

Comment: @svick well I mean a way of generating it without duplicating the nodes...

Comment: This isn't a binomial tree. It looks more like a deap.

Comment: @templatetypedef well is defined as that in some field of finance: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter45.html btw what's a deap ? You mean heap ?

Comment: A deap is an esoteric data structure that's pretty much obsolete these days.  It the DAG formed by turning a grid 45 degrees and connecting the nodes as you've drawn them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the structure level by level. In each iteration, create one level of nodes, put them in an array, and connect the previous level to them. Something like this (C#):

```cs
Node GenerateStructure(int levels)
{
    Node root = null;

    Node[] previous = null;

    for (int level = 1; level <= levels; level++)
    {
        int count = level;

        var current = new Node[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            current[i] = new Node();

        if (level == 1)
            root = current[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            previous[i].Left = current[i];
            previous[i].Right = current[i + 1];
        }

        previous = current;
    }

    return root;
}
```

The whole structure requires O(N^2) memory, where N is the number of level. This approach requires O(N) additional memory for the two arrays. Another approach would be to generate the graph from left to right, but that would require O(N) additional memory too.

The time complexity is obviously O(N^2).

Answer (score 1):

More than a tree, of which I would give a definition like 'connected graph of N vertex and N-1 edges', that structure seems like a Pascal (or Tartaglia, as teached in Italy) [triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). As such, an array with a suitable indexing suffices.

Details on construction depends on your data input: please give some more hint.

Comment: ok the Tartaglia triangle would probably be the way to go by indexing the node in some index based on the triangle level.